# HTML Image with float attribute ignores size information

Tags: html, css

I added a picture this way:

```
<img style="float: right;" src="images/wettautomaten/1.png" alt="" border="0" width="100" height="100"/>
```

It appears super big, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to add like this 
<img style="float: right;height:100px;width:100px;border:0" src="images/wettautomaten/1.png" alt="" />

Comment: check your css  in firebug

Comment: its working perfectly, I can't find any problem. http://jsfiddle.net/2j3hqnsf/

Comment: @NageshSanika Your answer is probably right, post it!

Answer (score 1):

Both the code above displayed are correct.But The style you written here is also depends upon another styles defined or attached in that web page.

Please check if you define another style for < img > tag.

or try another browser.

Regards